# Echo only current user details

Tags: php

please can someone help me with this code? It shows all the users’ info but i need it to show only the info of the logged user.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "username";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
$sql = "SELECT AEG FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 3) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "id: " . $row["AEG"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Add `WHERE` clause to your query.

Comment: How are you checking if user is logged in? By session or by database result? In other words. do you have 'loggedin' column or something, or does login store in session (which usually is the case)

Comment: Where is current logged user condition? Can you please add it?

Comment: What should that code be? @u_mulder, i can't get WHERE working :(

Comment: "_i can't get WHERE working_" Try to be a little more descriptive, _what_ exactly isn't working? `$sql = "SELECT AEG FROM users WHERE id=1";` should return only data for user with `id=1`, assuming `id` exists in your table (and there is a user with id=1). Adjust this to use the id of your currently logged in user, which you haven't posted how you get it, as others asked.

Comment: i know what you are saying but i want the id=current user id, i do not want to put the id of 1 or 2, it must select the current user.

Comment: That's why I added "_Adjust this to use the id of your currently logged in user_" in my comment. CommunityIsridiculous and DivyeshPrajapati already asked how you get the current user, which you didn't answer. Are you asking how to get the currently logged in user? If so, you should rephrase your questions title

Answer (score 0):

Upon login, store the email/username/id in a $_SESSION variable;

`$_SESSION['email'] = $email; // in this example I used email`

Then on your file, you can access session variables using $_SESSION['variable'] and use it on your sql statement;

My modifications are the ones with comments.

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $dbname = "username";

   /*Store session data in a variable*/
   $email = $_SESSION['email'];
   /**********************************/

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   /*Add where clause to your sql statement*/
   $sql = "SELECT AEG FROM users WHERE email ='".$email."'";
   /****************************************/

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 3) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "id: " . $row["AEG"]. "<br>";
     }
   } else {
     echo "0 results";
   }

   $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: sorry i am so confused now :( where must the "$_SESSION['email'] = $email; // in this example I used email" go? in the login page or the directed page after login?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one if you are having 4 user then it is showing only one

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
     echo "id: " . $row["AEG"]. "<br>";
  }
} 
else
{
   echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: it still echo all the users, not the current one